# Regular expression to match strings that contain <br/> but not other HTML tags?

Tags: php

I want to find and match strings that contain no HTML tags but <br/> and all other normal characters ([^<>]+).

So basically, this match dismisses any string that contains '<' or '>' but not '<br/>'.

This is what I can come up with:

```
preg_match('@[(?:<br/>).]+@sU', $str, $match);
```

Obviously it doesn't work cause' I don't know what to put at the dot. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not...

```
@(?:[^<]|<br */>)*@
```

That is, any number of (a complete `<br />` tag or any non-tag-opening character).

Answer (score 1):

I would just do it backwards -- see if the string contains any `<...>` tag other than `<br/>` and dismiss it if it does. So:

```
preg_match(/<(?!br)/i, $str, $match);
if (!$match) we_are_good();
```